# How do I center images within and HTML table using inline CSS?

Tags: html, css

In order to learn more about HTML, I am designing an HTML newsletter template from scratch. I got everything working properly. However , I have a section where I want to add 4 social media icons, distributed evenly across the table row.

I am trying to do this mostly with HTML and inline css due to the requirements of the various email software but I cant seem to get it to work. I've attached you can see what I mean (I'm building this on a local machine so no real images there). I just need the 4 images spread evenly across the row.

Thanks a lot in advance

```html
<!-- Start Social Media -->
     
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="560" style="padding: 25px 0px 0px 15px" bgcolor="#4e6591">
    <tr>
        <td style="font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; color:#ffffff"> <span style="padding-left: 50px; text-transform:uppercase; font-size:20px; font-weight:bold;">Connect with us</span>
            <br>
            <br>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>"
        <td align="center" valign="middle"> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="blank"><img src="facebook.png" alt="Facebook Follow" width="94px" height="32px" style="display: block;"></a>

        </td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle"> <a href="https://www.twitter.com/" target="blank"><img src="twitter.png" alt="Twitter Follow" width="94px" height="32px" style="display: block;"></a>

        </td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle"> <a href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="blank"><img src="youtube.png" alt="YouTube Subscribe" width="94px" height="31px" style="display: block;"></a>

        </td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle"> <a href="#" target="blank"><img src="rss.png" alt="RSS Subscribe" width="94px" height="32px" style="display: block;"></a>

        </td>
```

Comment: JSFiddle links are not allowed unless you also provide your code here.

Comment: Thanks, I just figured that out :)

Answer (score 1):

You need `colspan="4"` on the "Connect with us" table cell, so that it spans the four columns of the row below.

Comment: I know, but that's not my issue. The problem is getting the images to be centered within their individual cells

Comment: Thanks a lot @chipChocolate.py. That's exactly what I need, but what if I need 4 social media images instead of three?

Comment: @Mika90 Then adjust the `colspan` as necessary.

Comment: @chipChocolate. Thanks a lot, that was exactly what I needed. Thanks everyone for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

You are just missing the `colspan` on the first `tr td`. Add this and it should work.

You also seem to have some table padding which is causing an offset from the left. I would recommend adding it to the right as well as this will make everything seem off centre.

```html
<!-- Start Social Media -->

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="560" style="padding: 25px 0px 0px 15px" bgcolor="#4e6591">
  <tr>
    <td style="font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; color:#ffffff" colspan="4"> <span style="padding-left: 50px; text-transform:uppercase; font-size:20px; font-weight:bold;">Connect with us</span>
      <br>
      <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="blank">
        <img src="facebook.png" alt="Facebook Follow" width="94px" height="32px" style="display: block;">
      </a>

    </td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">
      <a href="https://www.twitter.com/" target="blank">
        <img src="twitter.png" alt="Twitter Follow" width="94px" height="32px" style="display: block;">
      </a>

    </td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="blank">
        <img src="youtube.png" alt="YouTube Subscribe" width="94px" height="31px" style="display: block;">
      </a>

    </td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">
      <a href="#" target="blank">
        <img src="rss.png" alt="RSS Subscribe" width="94px" height="32px" style="display: block;">
      </a>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Alternative's can be done in CSS and i would highly recommend learning CSS next on your journey into HTML and web development as CSS will be much more helpful and usable in future work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute **valign** for `td`.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td valign="middle">
      <img src="http://logonoid.com/images/stack-overflow-logo.png" height="30px">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azvEPW

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about centering the image in the table cell,

```
<td align="center">
```

or

```
<td style="text-align: center;">
```

So basically you add `text-align: center;` to your style

Comment: While you are answering the question, you aren't answering "the question". Read the question in full, understand what is happening, and then you'll realise the problem, which I mention in my own answer ;)

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking to achieve. And i have added both options, right now I'm at <td align="center" valign="middle"> and still the images do not get centered.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I believe the problem says "problem is getting the images to be centered within their individual cells".

Comment: @HarshulPandav Yes, and the *cause* of the problem is the missing `colspan` on the cell above them, causing the first image to take up the width of the header cell, and the remaining images to fill in smaller space afterwards.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I agree with you

And here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cEgRp/52/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="560" style="padding: 25px 0px 0px 15px" bgcolor="#4e6591">
    <tr>
        <td style="font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; color:#ffffff"> <span style="padding-left: 50px; text-transform:uppercase; font-size:20px; font-weight:bold;">Connect with us</span>
            <br>
            <br>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>"
        <td align="center" valign="middle"> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="blank"><img src="facebook.png" alt="Facebook Follow" width="94px" height="32px" style="display: block;margin:auto;"></a>

        </td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle"> <a href="https://www.twitter.com/" target="blank"><img src="twitter.png" alt="Twitter Follow" width="94px" height="32px" style="display: block;margin:auto;"></a>
    </td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle"> <a href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="blank"><img src="youtube.png" alt="YouTube Subscribe" width="94px" height="31px" style="display: block; margin:auto;"></a>

    </td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle"> <a href="#" target="blank"><img src="rss.png" alt="RSS Subscribe" width="94px" height="32px" style="display: block;margin:auto;"></a>

    </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set static size.

*100 / 4 = 25*

```
<td align="center" valign="middle" width="25%">
```

And that's better to change "*padding: 25px 0px 0px 15px*" to "*padding: 25px 0px 0px 0px*" because 15 set on the left of the table and shift all images to right.